# New install and I can't get Ubuntu to work

Tags: 13.04, usb, lock-screen, switch-user

First of all what happened > I made an Ubuntu live USB to install Ubuntu Raring Ringtail. After Ubuntu said that "it has installed successfully and you need to restart your computer" (Why it doesn't said that please remove any attached USB or CD/DVD before restart?) I thought it may require the USB further (I'm a newbie) so I didn't removed it. AFter restart Ubuntu started the installation setup again. Then I clicked cancel and quit the setup. It came to Desktop with a visible icon saying "install Ubuntu". I shut downed it but it got stuck in the shut down process. Finally I pulled the plug out and turned off my computer. I started it again. Is that a good install? With one mistake of Ubuntu to not telling me to deattach any connected USB, I had to do that. Now this is what I'm experiencing:

1. It is always getting hanged while switching accounts. The other account just blink here and there, shows a cropped part of the desktop with nothing clickable. So cold reboot is the only method to get rid of it as I can't do anything. (In the last I've disabled all accounts including Guest).
2. While on lock screen the button "Switch account" is unclickable. It is just faded away and only sometimes appear to be clickable but mostly not.
3. Even after selecting Automatic login to off, it is not asking me for my password during startup and I only have to click login to go to my destop.
4. As I Lock my screen, screen just turn black (why?) and only after waving my mouse a bit or pressing any key make the password field apppear.
5. I can't rely on Ubuntu. Should I?

My comp. specs:
Processer: Intel Core 2 Duo
RAM: 1 GB
Video Memory: 128 MB

---

Bonus Big Mistake of Ubuntu: When installing, I chose Replace Windows XP with Ubuntu. Ah! I thought it will just replace my windows XP but it wiped out my whole disk and eveything. WTF!

Comment: I'm not going to recover my files. I just can't mess with things burdening my mind. Those were not much important files anyway but that was big 70 GB stuff I've lost including movies and very useful Windows softwares and my dropbox files which because of my slow internet I'm not going to download all that 1 GB stuff again. <note: the comment to which this reply is seems to be deleted>

Comment: According to my computer specs and strange things that happened should I keep Ubuntu running or switch back to Windows? @belacqua

Comment: Well, there are no problem with the specs and Ubuntu.  I think you probably need a clean install, is all.

Comment: @belacqua clean install means? didn't I already clean isntalled it as it wiped out my whole disk and installed on it.

Comment: All I mean by clean install is a new installation where you don't have problems during the installation.  My reading was that it sounded like there were complications.

Comment: Assuming you don't have any important files on your computer right now, you would want to wipe everything again and install again. (This time without having any installation problems).

Comment: I installed it again by selecting partitions manually + formatting them. There seems some improvement. I hope now it should not behave weirdly. The only things that I'm seeing now is when logging in. It isn't as normal as in Windows. My screen resolution lowers and it get stretched having just wallpaper and nothing. Then icons and everything comes. And now I'm not going to add any accounts. Thanks for your reply @belacqua